# How do I get the character before a specific character with regex?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have this String : `"2x+10=100"`.
Now I want to know what character the character before the 100 is.
How can I get this with regex?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO, it is always recommended to post 3 simple things in your post. 1- Sample of input, 2- sample of output, 3- your efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem, kindly do update your post and let us know then?

Comment: Do you want everything before the 100?

Comment: Do you have to use a regex? `indexOf`? `string.substring(-1 + string.indexOf("100"), string.indexOf("100"))`

Comment: only the one character before it.

Comment: Why regex?  This is nuking the mosquito.

Comment: Well I thought regex would be a good idea, but i dont have to be.

Comment: Just use `myString.charAt(myString.indexOf("100")-1)`, along with some error checking for the case when `100` isn't in the string, or is at the start of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following. It will give 1 character just before 100.

```
.(?=100)
```

[Regex Demo:](https://regex101.com/r/xN1Im1/7)

Or in case you need to match character which comes before last 100(considering that if in case there are multiple 100 occurrences and you need last 100 one's value) then try following.

```
.(?=100$)
```

Brief Explanation: Using Positive look forward/ahead method here and making sure if 100 is coming in it `(?=100)` then mentioning `.` a DOT before it to get very first character before 100.

Answer (score 2):

Other answerers are correct that `(.)100` is the regex necessary for this match, but I find that sometimes the specifics of using regex can confuse a new user. Since your question is tagged with Java, here is a sample of java code that shows regex being used, based off of [this code sample](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaregex/javaregex_capturing_groups.htm).

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexMatches {
   public static void main( String args[] ) {
      // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
      String line = "2x+10=100";
      String pattern = "(.)100";

      // Create a Pattern object
      Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

      // Now create matcher object.
      Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

      if (m.find( )) {
         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
      } else {
         System.out.println("NO MATCH");
      }
   }
}
```

You can also benefit from sites like [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) to help you play around with regex and learn how to construct your own patterns.

Comment: That prints `=100`, not just the character before `100`. Did you mean to print `group(1)`?

Comment: Thanks for the correction! This is exactly the reason that I wanted to provide a more complete code example instead of just (.)100, because of mistakes like this.

Answer (score 0):

This regex looks for any single character before "100" and capture it in first group: `(.)100`. The parentheses means capture-group. The dot means any single character.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *capturing group* to get a portion of the matching string.  For example, this code:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("([a-z]+)[0-9]+").matcher("abc456");
assert matcher.matches();
System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

Prints out:

```
abc
```

See also: [Java Pattern class docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).